# How to correctly use q.denodeify

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I am trying to learn how to use the q module and the denodeify method. When I run my code, I see the console log "Inside Add()" but nothing else gets logged. I want the code to also log "Addition function completed". Can someone tell me where my code went wrong?

```
var Q = require('q')

function Add() {
    var a, b, c
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = a + b
    console.log("Inside Add()")
}

var display_promise = Q.denodeify(Add)

display_promise().then(function() {
    console.log("Addition function completed")
}, function() {s
    console.log("Error")
})
```

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in your code, why are you using promises? And `Add` doesn't take a node-style asynchronous callback, so there's no reason to `denodeify` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`denodify` only makes sense for functions that use the typical Node.js idiom of accepting a callback function, because those functions perform asynchronous operations. The function `Add` does neither.

You could rewrite it to accept a callback that it will call when it's done:

```
function Add(callback) {
    var a, b, c
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = a + b
    console.log("Inside Add()")
    callback();
}
```

However, strictly speaking that doesn't make a lot of sense, because `Add` still only executes synchronous code.

You could add some asynchronocity to it as well:

```
function Add(callback) {
    console.log("Inside Add()")
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a, b, c
      a = 5
      b = 6
      c = a + b
      callback();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Q's documentation shows other example of `q.denodify`, like promisifying `fs.readFile`:

```
var readFile = Q.denodeify(fs.readFile);
readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8").then(...);
```

Starting with Node v10, there's also an (experimental) promises-based version of `fs` built into Node:

```
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises;

readFile(...).then(...)
```

And also a `q.denodify` equivalent called `util.promisify`:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
readFile(...).then(...);
```

Comment: "*much like the rest of the `q` module*" - actually [only very few functions deal with node-style interfaces](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks), the rest of the Q module is a very rich generic promise API. (In fact much richer than most of today's libraries, as the pioneering work of Q got us the experience which of them were more useful and which less needed).

Comment: @Bergi fair enough :)